# If someone logs into their steam on my computer and downloads a game will we be able to play multiplayer together?

Tags: steam

So around last year a buddy of mine bought ark on his stream account and downloaded it to my old computer. I was able to play it even though I never really paid for it. Steam just sent a email to the buyer of the game asking him if it was ok that his game can be played on my account. He agreed and I was able to play. Well for five minutes then my computer to a turn for the worse since it couldn't handle the game. Anyway new computer and ready to try again. My question is, if said friend logs into his steam on my computer and downloads Ark Survival Evolved. If I log back into my account and start playing will him and I be able to play ark together on the same map? Or will it only allow one of us to play it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because the game is linked to the steam account and you can't login into the same account twice. So your friend can login, play, but you can't, and vice versa. The possible duplicate mentions family sharing, which won't work either since you can't play at the same time then.

The only way to actually play together is both of you buying it. There is no legitimate way around this limitiation.